# Any utilities to print all fields of a javax.servlet.http.Cookie

Tags: java, spring, debugging, cookies, apache-commons

I have a

```
javax.servlet.http.Cookie
```

object in my java+spring application.

Do you know of any utility class that will print all fields of a cookie?

[image]Thanks.

Comment: This is trivial to do by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to try with this:

```
private String getCookieString(Cookie[] cookies){
    if(cookies == null)
        return "null";
    StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner(",","[","]");
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
          stringJoiner.add(ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(cookie));
        }
    return stringJoiner.toString();
}
```